# Any risk in a AutoCloseable wrapper for java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock?

Tags: java, raii, try-with-resources, auto-close

With [`try-with-resource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) introduced in Java 7, I was surprised to see that that the [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) has not been retrofitted to be an [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). It seemed fairly simple, so I have added it myself as follows:

```
class Lock implements AutoCloseable {
    private final java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock _lock;
    Lock(java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock lock) {
        _lock = lock;
        _lock.lock();
    }
    @Override 
    public void close() {
        _lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This works with an `AutoCloseableReentrantReadWiteLock` class and usage is as follows:

```
try (AutoCloseableReentrantReadWiteLock.Lock l = _lock.writeLock()) {
    // do something
}
```

Since this seems so straightforward and canonical use of auto-closing [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) I am thinking there must be a good reason this should not be done. Anybody know?

Comment: @rxg I am going to revert most of your edit, my surprise wasn't when it was introduced, but recently when I used it for a lock

Comment: No probs, but can you fix the link for AutoCloseable?

Answer (score 23):

This was a big debate when `try-with-resources` was proposed in February/March 2009.

Josh Bloch, the author of the proposal, said "[This construct was designed for one thing and one thing only: resource management.  It was not designed for locking.](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000157.html)"

There was a separate proposal to cover locks separately, but it didn't get anywhere.

I think the main reasons locks were not covered were:

- not possible to add methods to an interface in Java 7
- performance hit of creating an extra wrapper object that implemented the correct interface
- philosophical objections to `Lock` being a different kind of resource from file handles (e.g. creation of a `Lock` does not entail invoking the `lock` method)

You can follow all the historical argy-bargy on [the archive page](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/ProjectCoin/Proposal2009AutomaticResourceManagement), for example [this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2011-February/003114.html).

Comment: Thank you for the info; to me the lock seems like a resource but perhaps there are things I am missing. Working in Spring world, performance hit from wrappers is irrelevant.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: A lock is a resource, at least for me and Dijkstra (:D), see e.g. [the Banker's algorithm description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker's_algorithm#Resources). It's not necessary to create a new object each time (you only need something having a `close` method and can use it multiple times).

Comment: @maaartinus I am afraid I don't understand what you are saying. If you have a close method then you also need an open method, which is what the create does for the Lock class.

Comment: @Miserable Variable: You need an "open" method, but it can look like `AutoCloseable open() {lock(); return myCloseable;}` where `myCloseable` is a final field (and "closing" it obviously unlocks the lock).

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Sorry, I was confused... you're doing it right.

Comment: Is this answer still up to date for Java?