# Why didn't Java 8 add `withLock` default methods to the `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` interface?

Tags: locking, java-8, default-method

Along the same lines as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574353/991432), I wonder why the Java team didn't add a few default methods to the [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface, something like this:

```
public default void withLock(Runnable r) {
  lock();

  try {
     r.run();
  } finally {
     unlock();
  }
}
```

This would allow a programmer to do

```
public class ThreadSafe {
  // Object requiring protection
  private final List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public void mutate(String s) {
    lock.withLock(() -> l.add(s));
  }

  public void threadSafeMethod {
    lock.withLock(() -> { System.out.println(l.get(l.size())); });
  }
}
```

instead of

```
public void threadSafeMethod {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    System.out.println(l.get(l.size())); 
  } finally { 
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the answer to this one is similar to the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574353/991432) - it was deemed an 'attractive nuisance', due to the allocation cost of the `Runnable` created from the lambda (see [Brian Goetz's response](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-October/011874.html) to the request).

The good news is that there is [an open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025597) for this request, which means that Oracle seems open to revisiting this decision once the JVM can reliably minimise the allocation cost.

Comment: As a side comment, Brian's example `withLock( () -> { counter++; } );` cannot possibly be a capturing lambda because `counter` in that example cannot be a local variable. But we get the point, and actually the limitation that you can't mutate a local var within such a `withLock`, or issue `return` and other early-exit control statements, may be an even stronger argument against it.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: the example `() -> counter++` *is* a capturing lambda but it works only if `counter` is a member variable so the lambda remembers the immutable reference to `this` (or the class in case of a `static` variable). Note that if `counter` was a local variable not only the lambda didn’t work, it turned the entire example pointless as there is no reason why an update to a *local* variable should be guarded by a `Lock`.

Comment: @Holger There seems to be a terminological misalignment: my point was that it is not a *closure* as it doesn't close over local variables (I assumed this was synonymous with "capturing lambda"). This means that the example does not demonstrate any performance issues, therefore does not serve to explain why `withLock` wasn't included in the API. Your additional point that the example would be fruitless if `counter` was a local var reinforces this.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Brian Goetz’ explanation targets the issue that with the current lambda implementation a new instance is created for every invocation when the lambda has state ([see my explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339/2711488)). It doesn’t matter whether it captures `this` or `counter`, a lambda useful in this context will always have state and hence produce a new instance every time. So his statement is correct regarding “capturing”. However, I don’t see why this small performance issue should drive API design decisions here when it is ignored for all other APIs…

Comment: @Holger A reasonable expectation would be that a `this`-capturing lambda would be accessible from the object referred to by `this`, not involving any hashtable-backed lambda cache. Also, I think your use of the term "call site" does not refer to call sites, but rather to lambda creation sites.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: the term “call site” origins from the `invokedynamic` concept. See, even the object returned by `LambdaMetaFactory` has the type `CallSite`. This is the “lambda creation site” if `invokedynamic` is used for lambda creation. I’m sorry if this creates confusions. As of current lambda implementation, lambda capturing `this` are not cached. And, as said, it’s not even clear whether caching would be any good (let’s say, if the JVM has a good escape analysis). That’s why I don’t understand the reasoning to not include the discussed method.

Comment: @Holger Escape analysis would be only good for *downward funargs*. Granted, that covers the majority of use cases for `withLock`. Generally we agree that the argumentation is insufficent, especially because those rare cases where performance is of utmost concern could always revert to the "exploded" idiom.

Comment: The linked bug has been closed. Brian writes: "While we're not ruling out the possibility of doing this in the future, that future is far away. Closing because so much has to happen before this becomes a viable approach."